# How to download Ubuntu keyboard layout?

Tags: keyboard, keyboard-layout, layout

Is there any way to download keyboard layouts available in Ubuntu so I can use them on Windows? 
I would like to be able to use the same layouts on both OS, I especially enjoy default Esperano layout and additional arrows in "regular" languages. 
It will be nice if the method was a faster one than creating (by coping) a new layout in windows "Keyboard layout Creator" but also not very complicated.

Comment: Seems like this has been asked before on a lot of stack exchange sites and the answer has been the same. "Nope". However this questions is probably off topic as your truly asking a windows question. You can try MSDN sites or google, but I don't think your going to find an answer you want.